# IF EXIST clause

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my table:

```
ID      COUNTRY_CODE_3D     COUNTRY_CODE_2D      TYPE_ID    
 1          "IND"            "IN"                  11           
 2          "CAN"            "CA"                  13           
 3           null            null                  17
```

I want a select query which will return a single row 
if `COUNTRY_CODE_2D = 'CA'` (valid data) return 2nd row, else return the 3rd row where `COUNTRY_CODE_2D =null and TYPE_ID=17`

Comment: Can you reorganise your question so it makes more sense? Maybe show an image of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can put a functional index on country_code_2d, (`NVL(country_code_2d,'EMPTY')` )

```
CREATE INDEX fidx_empty_null ON country_cnfg_tbl (NVL(country_code_2d,'EMPTY'));
```

,you can then

```
SELECT * FROM country_cnfg_tbl a
WHERE NVL(a.country_code_2d,'EMPTY') IN 
(  
    SELECT NVL(b.country_code_2d,'EMPTY') FROM dual d
    LEFT JOIN country_cnfg_tbl b on b.country_code_2d = 'CA'
)
```

Or Without joins (and more portable as it does not use the oracle table `DUAL`)

```
SELECT * FROM country_cnfg_tbl a WHERE NVL(a.country_code_2d,'EMPTY') IN  
(       
    SELECT CASE WHEN count(*) = 0 THEN 
                'EMPTY' 
           ELSE 
                b.country_code_2d 
           END as country_code_2d  
    FROM country_cnfg_tbl b 
    WHERE b.country_code_2d = 'CA'
    GROUP BY b.country_code_2d
)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.but if 'CAA' does not exist it return a row which has all null values ,I want a row which should return a row from this country_cnfg_tbl table which has b.country_code_2d = null

Comment: I ment if b.country_code_2d = 'CAA' does not exist it should return row where b.country_code_2d = null from same table,If possible can you give a query without any join ,Thank you..

Comment: That is exactly what the query does !!

Comment: No ,It returns a null row where all the column value are null but i want a row from table country_cnfg_tbl where country_code_2d =null which has some values in other clumns because in my table country_cnfg_tbl there is one row where column country_code_2d =null but other columns have some values.

Comment: Kevin there is a error while executing ur query (without join)  Error : ORA-00937:not a single-group group function .

Answer (score 1):

Thank You Kevin,Florin for your help.

Kevin, the second query you gave me had 1 error. But I changed few things and its working fine now, Kevin thanks for you valuable inputs, keep up the good work :)

This is the final query:

```
SELECT * FROM country_cnfg_tbl a WHERE NVL(a.country_code_2d,'EMPTY') IN
(SELECT 
CASE
WHEN (select count(*) FROM country_cnfg_tbl WHERE country_code_2d IN ('CA') OR country_code_2d IS NULL) = 1  THEN 'EMPTY'  ELSE country_code_2d
END as country_code_2d  FROM country_cnfg_tbl WHERE country_code_2d IN ('CA') OR country_code_2d IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example without explicit joins:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  country_cnfg_tbl 
WHERE 
  nvl(country_code_2d,'xxx') 
   = 
  (select nvl(country_code_2d,'xxx') 
   from country_cnfg_tbl 
   where country_code_2d='CA')
```

But I assure you that Kevin Burton's answer is better :) I voted it :))